# Dynamic casting. ClassCastException

Tags: java, dynamic, casting, classcastexception

everybody =)
I'm trying to cast a string to Double this way

```
Class.forName("java.lang.Double").cast("100")
```

But it throws ClassCastException. :(
What's wrong with this? And how can I achieve what I want.

Comment: Because it's wrong, that's why you're getting the error -- so don't do it this way, and read the API as it would have told you this. Instead parse the String via Double.parseDouble.

Comment: I know this, but I can't use it coz I do not know what type I need to cast to in compile time.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What are the possible values for the input string? Where are you going to store the result? Why do you need this?

Comment: @Tror: Well you can't use stuff that you just make up out of thin air either, like trying to cast a String to a double. Why don't you tell us all the requirements and pertinent details of your problem then? Otherwise we have little chance of being able to help  you.

Comment: @Tror: please update your original question and supply any information necessary for others to be able to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot cast a `String` do `Double`. If you want to get the `Double` representation for a `String`, you can either:

```
Double d = new Double("100");
```

or

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("100");
```

Comment: I know this, but I can't use it coz I do not know what type I need to cast to in compile time.

Comment: I wonder if we're supposed to magically guess just what his requirements and constraints are.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially trying to cast a String to Double like so

```
String s = "100";
Double d = (Double)s;
```

You can't do that. This is the reason for your ClassCastException.

You need to use [Double.valueOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)